# navigation controller push another controller trigger tableview call scrollViewDidScroll:

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview in the root view controller of a navigation controller. 
And I use the JBParallaxCell for main view and segue into detailView, then return form detailview to JBParallaxCell and it will reset the imageView position.

JBParallaxCell is used to create a parallax image view in the tableview. However the image blinks when navigation controller push back to the tableview because it resets the position of the image view.

How could I fix this bug?
Thanks for any help!

Here are some code snippet:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Get visible cells on table view.
    NSArray *visibleCells = [self.tableView visibleCells];

    for (JBParallaxCell *cell in visibleCells)
    {
        [cell cellOnTableView:self.tableView didScrollOnView:self.view];
    }

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    JBViewController *controller = [[JBViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

JBParallaxCell.h:

```
@interface JBParallaxCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *parallaxImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *subtitleLabel;

- (void)cellOnTableView:(UITableView *)tableView didScrollOnView:(UIView *)view;

@end
```

JBParallaxCell.m:

```
@implementation JBParallaxCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)cellOnTableView:(UITableView *)tableView didScrollOnView:(UIView *)view
{
    NSLog(@"cell scrolling...");
    CGRect rectInSuperview = [tableView convertRect:self.frame toView:view];

    float distanceFromCenter = CGRectGetHeight(view.frame)/2 - CGRectGetMinY(rectInSuperview);
    float difference = CGRectGetHeight(self.parallaxImage.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.frame);
    float move = (distanceFromCenter / CGRectGetHeight(view.frame)) * difference;


    CGRect imageRect = self.parallaxImage.frame;
    imageRect.origin.y = -(difference/2)+move;
    self.parallaxImage.frame = imageRect;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the similar problem, after I call `popViewControllerAnimated:YES` from view controller, my table view is scrolled to the top position automatically.

And I think this is a bug of IOS7/8.
In IOS9+ it is alright.

The more the `estimatedRowHeight` differs from the actual height, the more the table will jump when the push segue happens.

After **comment** this line:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 64.0;
```

`UITableView` didn't jump any more.